# Jquery not working anymore since php includes and external file import

Tags: php, jquery, file, include, external

I noticed my jquery code is not working anymore since I started doing some php includes.

Obviously, I would like my code to be imported from a js file from the index.php main page. However, my html code will be generated from php includes (i dunno if this could be a problem).

Anyway, here is the structure of my php page (index.php) :

```
[...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/comments.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// HEADER -----------------------------------------------
include("front/index/header.php");
// ------------------------------------------------------
?>

<div class="containerMiddleFullSize">
<div class="containerMiddle">

<?php

// BODY -------------------------------------------------
if ($_GET['page'] == "home")
{
    include("front/index/home.php");
}
[...]
```

Here is my jquery code (js/comments.js) :

```
$(function() 
{

$(".content").Watermark("Écrire un commentaire...");

$(".content").focus(function()
{
$(this).height("50px"); //animate({"height": "50px",}, "fast" );
$(this).next(".button_block").slideDown("fast");

return false;
});

$(".cancel").click(function()

$(this).parent(".button_block").slideUp("fast").prev(".content").height("18px");
return false;
//}
});

});
```

Any help welcome ;)

Cheers,

Gotye.

Comment: What is in your `front/index/header.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the definitions to use the live function e.g.

```
$(".cancel").live("click", function() { ...
```

I'm guessing that at the time your JS is called, the elements in question don't exist therefore nothing is bound to them. Using live ensures that any future elements with the specified characteristics, will be bound correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that your Javascript is working fine as long as you don't include your PHP files.
But, it stops working once you make those include.
So, Please verify that you don't have any unclosed HTML tags. Sometimes, incomplete tags creates the problem for JS to work.

Thanks!
Hussain

Answer (score 0):

maybe you cut and pasted this wrong but maybe add in an open bracket for the onclick function?
change:

```
 $(".cancel").click(function()

 $(this).parent(".button_block").slideUp("fast").prev(".content").height("18px");
 return false;
 //}
 });
```

to:

```
 $(".cancel").click(function()
 {
   $(this).parent(".button_block").slideUp("fast").prev(".content").height("18px");
   return false;
 });
```